# hdinsight pig job submit 502 error

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-pig, azure-hdinsight

I am getting a 502 error when submitting a pig job to an hdinsight cluster. Any ideas on how to fix the cluster? Last time i got this error i deleted the cluster and created it again, would like to find a better way to fix the error. here is the error that I am getting:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.WebRequest.HttpLayerException: Request failed with code:BadGateway
Content:<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.</h2>
  <h3>There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.WebHCatRest.HadoopRemoteJobSubmissionRestClient.<SendRequestWithErrorChecking>d__2f.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.WebHCatRest.HadoopRemoteJobSubmissionRestClient.<MakeAsyncJobSubmissionRequest>d__25.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.WebHCatRest.HadoopRemoteJobSubmissionRestClient.<SubmitPigJob>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.Hadoop.Client.HadoopJobSubmissionPocoClient.RemoteHadoop.RemoteHadoopJobSubmissionPocoClient.<SubmitPigJob>d__1d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.PocoClient.HDInsightJobSubmissionPocoClient.<SubmitPigJob>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.<CreatePigJobAsync>d__16.MoveNext()

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.TaskExtensions.WaitForResult[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.Framework.Core.Library.TaskExtensions.WaitForResult[T](Task`1 task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsight.JobSubmission.HDInsightHadoopClient.CreatePigJob(PigJobCreateParameters pigJobCreateParameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for the trouble here, that should not be happening. Are you still experiencing this behavior?  If possible, can you follow up with me in email (mwinkle at microsoft), or by opening a support ticket via [the support portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/?getsupport=true)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but regarding Hive. To resolve my issue I restarted the apache services on the head node.

1. Enable Remote Connection through Azure
2. Login to the server
3. Open the Task Manager
4. Open the Services Tab
5. Sort by Description
6. Restart the Services with a description of Apache Hadoop...

After those steps, try submitting a job.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already been asked on MSDN.  It appears you are hitting a known bug between HDInsight and Azure Storage on lightly loaded clusters.  See this link for documentation for a fix: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6bd04e9-e69b-4e96-b2ef-fa8abcf3bbc3/502-error-in-hbase-cluster?forum=hdinsight